# how to sort same string array into a new string and count it.

Tags: java, arrays

I'm doing a java project and I want sort same string array then count how many each car brand have. I am stuck passing an array into int variable. need suggestions. thanks.

```
public class SortCars {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] cars = {"honda", "toyota", "honda", "toyota"};
    String[] honda = new String[5];
    String[] toyota = new String[5];
    int numOfHonda;
    int numOfToyota;

    for (int i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
        if (cars[i].equals("numOfHonda")) { //
            honda[i] = cars[i];
            honda[i] = numOfHonda; // stuck here 
            numOfHonda++;
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: sounds like you want a `Map<String, Integer>`

Comment: What do you want to achieve ? Just counting how many Hondas and Toyotas , or splitting it into two collections ?

Comment: splitting them into two collection into array and then tracking them how many honda or toyota in each array.

Comment: Use TreeMap. Best solution for it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have confusion with String and int values. Since you say you are in the beginning week of your programming and From what I understand from the question. This is what you are trying to do:-

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] cars = {"honda", "toyota", "honda", "toyota"};
    String[] honda = new String[5];
    String[] toyota = new String[5];
    int numOfHonda = 0;  // you need to initialize these int variables
    int numOfToyota = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
        if (cars[i].equals("honda")) { // if cars has element honda
            honda[i] = cars[i];        // putting cars element in honda array
            numOfHonda++;             //incrementing value of numOfHonda by 1
        }
        else if(cars[i].equals("toyota")){
        toyota[i] = cars[i];
        numofToyota++;

    }
 }
```

Now Printing numOfHonda and numofToyota will give you the number of Hondas and Toyotas respectively.

Apart from my answer, I would like to address some errors that I found in your code.

```
int numOfHonda;     //initilize your variable. Otherwise you will get compilation error! make it  = 0 in this case.
int numOfToyota;    // same here, initialize to 0.
```

`if (cars[i].equals("numOfHonda"))`

Here you are trying to compare cars[i] element to a string "numOfHonda".If you look at your code there is no such String declared as "numofHonda".  There is one thing which is an *int type variable*

*equals() method does not compare int type with String. It always compares String with String*. And the fact that you have put your int variable *numofHonda* inside " " does not make it the same thing! "numofHonda" and numHonda are different things!

`honda[i] = numOfHonda;`

You were stuck here because you know what you are doing here? 
you are trying to put int type variable(numOfHonda is of int type remember?)
inside a String array. This is not possible. It is a type mismatch. The basic definition of Any type of Array is it holds the same type of elements. So *honda[]* can not store an int type value.

Hope you have a better view now. Keep Learning.

Comment: If this is not what you wanted. Feel free to comment!

Comment: Thank you. this clear out a lot of my confusion. like you mentioned i was confuse trying to put string array into int. I've should of mention i"m just in beginning of my course.

Comment: @Rnhep if you don't mind, if this answer sufficed for you. Can you mark it as the accepted answer?

Answer (score 1):

It will be quite simple if you're allowed to use [Java 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html). Here's the code.

```
String[] cars = {"honda", "toyota", "honda", "toyota"};
Map<String, Long> data = Arrays.stream(cars)
  .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
System.out.println(data); // => {toyota=2, honda=2}
```

Comment: first thank you. but not sure if we can use that, we into a first week of programing so this code look more advance then where we at.

Answer (score 1):

Use TreeMap- Simple and precise solution

```
String[] cars = {"honda", "toyota", "honda", "toyota"};

TreeMap<String, Integer> map = new TreeMap<>();

for(String s: cars){
    int count = map.containsKey(s) ? map.get(s) : 0;
    map.put(s, count+1);
}

System.out.println(map);
```

output

```
{honda=2, toyota=2}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want to go over an array of cars and sort it into different array depending on there manufacturer? If so, here's my approach:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

String[] cars = {"honda", "toyota", "honda", "toyota"};
ArrayList<String> honda = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> toyota = new ArrayList<String>();

for (int i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
    switch(cars[i]) {
        case "honda":
            honda.add(cars[i]);
        break;
        case "toyota":
            toyota(cars[i]);
        break;
    }
}
```

I would suggest to use ArrayList (java.util.ArrayList) much more versatile. Furthermore I would use a switch-statement. And counting the amount of each manufacturer seems unnecessary to me, just check via `honda.length`.

---

### EDIT: in depth explanation

#### ArrayList

Okay, so here it is step by step. My Code does not really differs too much from yours. I change the manufacturer array to by [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) which is a 'CustomDatatype'. Under the hood it uses an array but it provides us with a few functionalities which make it easier to interact with this array (e.g. the `.add()` method to easily add an element to the ArrayList). To initialize an ArrayList we need to call the `new`-keyword since it a class not a basic datatype. We also need to tell the Array what datatype the element inside it have, this is what we to with the angle brackets (`ArrayList<ELEMENT_DATATYPE>()`)

#### switch()

The [switch statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) take whatever you 'give' it as the parameter in parentheses and tries to match it with the cases defined in the switch function. If a match is found it runs whatever code is defined by the case. Switch statements also have the ability to have fall through which keeps checking for matches even when the first is found, this can be useful but for now the prevent this with using the `break`-statement. A proper switch-case also has a `default` case which will run when no match is found, but this is also left out here due to complexity. (@otherDevs: sue me, I'm trying to explain things)

#### Conclusion

I tried to show a way using your approach and slightly changing it but in general it is the same, of course there a many ways to solve this stuff like `Map` and so on. But as you're just starting I recommend going with the basics. **AND** you really should get familiar with the Java-Docs since having the ability to read and use docs it pure gold as a developer.

Comment: first thank you, then yes. i want to have honda and toyota in their own array. i'm into the first week of programing so not a lot i can understand yet.

Comment: updated my answers and tried to explain it more detailed